# Woocommerce - How to add settings fields to existing or newly created shipping methods programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hope someone can help me out with this. I need to add a setting field to all the shipping methods being created in WooCommerce.

By default the options are:

- Method title
- Tax status
- Cost

How do I add an additional field there so that the options are:

- Method title
- Tax status
- Cost
- Code

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be very complicated, a real development like. Can you tell us what do you want to do with that code, or why do you need it?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for your comment. I figured as much as I've been looking for a solution for quite a while before asking here. Basically I have written an extension for wooCommerce that integrates with an accounting system. The shipping items are loaded in the accounting system each with their own sku/code. So I / the user need to be able to "link" the shipping method with accounting system via the code in order for it to successfully, and correctly, add the item to the accounting system invoice.

Answer (score 1):

With these snippet of code you can set new custom shipping method with additional setting field "Code"

```
function imp_shipping_method_init() {
    class Imp_WC_Pickup_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
        /**
         * Constructor for your shipping class
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $this->id                 = 'imp_pickup_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
            $this->method_title       = "Custom shipping method";  // Title shown in admin

            $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
            $this->title              = "Custom shipping method"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

            $this->enabled = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
            $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );

            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

            $this->init();
        }

        /**
         * Init your settings
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */
        function init() {
            // Load the settings API
            $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
            $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

            // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
        }

        public function init_form_fields() {
            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'     => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'       => 'checkbox',
                    'default'     => 'yes'
                ),

                'title' => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Method Title', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'description'   => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default'       => __( 'Custom Shipping Method', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                ),

                'code' => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Code', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'description'   => __( 'Code', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default'       => __( 'Code', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                ), 
            );
        }

        /**
         * calculate_shipping function.
         *
         * @access public
         * @param mixed $package
         * @return void
         */
        public function calculate_shipping( $package=array() ) {
            $rate = array(
                'id' => $this->id,
                'label' => $this->title,
                // 'cost' => '100',
                // 'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
            );

            // Register the rate
            $this->add_rate( $rate );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'imp_shipping_method_init' );

function add_your_shipping_method( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'Imp_WC_Pickup_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method' );
```

Then you can find new custom method and additional setting code on a woocommerce settings > shipping tab

[image]

After it you can get these additional filed on cart-shipping.php template with these snippet of code

```
$shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();

foreach ( $shipping_methods as $key => $shipping_method ) {

    $code = $shipping_method->settings->code;
}
```

Similarly you can try deregister default shipping woocomerce methods and register new customs with the same functionality and with new additional setting "Code"

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. 

However, this solution will not work as it requires creating a new shipping method. I need to hook into all existing shipping methods.